# DynamoDB - avoid data overwrite with primary partition key remaining the same for all data points

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm working on migrating the data from csv file stored in s3 to a table in DynamoDB. The code seems working but only the last data point is being posted on DynamoDB. The primary partition key (serial) is same for all data points. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import  boto3
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('scan_records')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=s3_file_name)
    data = resp['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    scan_time = data.split("\n")
    for scan in scan_time:
        print(scan)
        scan_data = scan.split(",")

    # Add it to dynamoDB

    try: 
         table.put_item(
         Item  = {
            'serial' : scan_data[0],
            'time' : scan_data[1],
        }
    )

    except Exception as e:
        print("End of File")
```

Comment: Is there a sort-key defined on the table?

Comment: Primary partition key - "Serial" and Primary sort key - "Time"

Comment: Found the solution. Serial+Time results in unique entry into DynamoDB

Answer (score 2):

in your dynamoDb table your Primary key needs to be unique for each elements in the table. So if the your primary key is only composed of a partition key that is the same for all your data point you will always have the same element overwritten. 
* You could add to your table a sort key that uses another field so that the partition key, sort key pair composing the primary key is unique and hence appending data to your table.
* If you can't have a unique primary key composed from your data points you can always add an UUID to the primary key to make it unique.

Comment: So I do have primary sort key  which is "time". Any suggestions on how to use combination of partition and sort key to tell DynamoDB it is a unique data. Thank in advance for your help here.

Comment: Be aware that serial+time must be unique for each unique record. If your system can generate records with the same serial+time value, e.g. from 2 parallel processes, then serial+time will result in you losing data (unless you make use of conditional inserts to prevents accidental overwrite).

Comment: Understood. Thank you Jarmod.

Comment: Found the solution. Serial+Time results in unique entry into DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

`ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(serial) AND attribute_not_exists(time)',`

Upon doing below two changes the issue was resolved and the code works fine. 
1. Unique entry checked with the combination of partition and sort key 
2. Add loop to go line by line in the csv file and ingest the data into DynamoDB.

Happy to share the code if anyone finds it useful.

Comment: Short, code-only answers are often frowned upon on Stack Overflow. In order to avoid being flagged as 'low quality', consider adding some explanatory text.